# Mask IP Address for MongoDB Connection String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, server

**Summary**

Hi I am Using a Linode Server Machine to Host a MongoDB Database,
My Connection String Looks something like this:

```sh
mongodb://username:password@192.168.123.145:27017,129.547.965.154:27017,165.698.120.047/somedb?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**Problem**

Notice How this will expose the IP Address of the Machines as Well
I can't find how to mask these IP addresses with another name like *test.mongo.com* or something.

***Please Help in Getting these Masked***

Comment: This would expose the IPs *where*? This should be internal configuration, where are you using that string where seeing the IPs would be a problem of any sort?

Comment: I don't understand it myself but https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/initial-dns-seedlist-discovery/initial-dns-seedlist-discovery.rst might be the way to go. That will allow you to use `mongodb+srv://` as a protocol. however it's worth noting that your IP addresses will always be discoverable somehow because whoever needs to connect to Mongo needs to know the IP to connect to. Another solution is to move the servers behind a proxy and pass the IP of that instead

Comment: Put IP and credentials (I wonder why you are concerned about the IP Address but not about the password) in an Environment variable and use these variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you mask an IP still there is a chance for your IP to get exposed. As anybody can simply check your domain DNS records and find the MongoDB server's IP address. I'd suggest you keep what you have right now and focus on security. To project your MongoDB a good password and moreover, a good firewall configuration is enough. You may put a good password and use your server's firewall to grant specific IPs to access your server's port `27017`. In this way, even they can see your IP they can't use your MongoDB server unless you whitelist their IP in the firewall.

Comment: I Have Password and keyfile authentication along with ufw set to accept 27017 port requests only from my node app server, Is that enough or i need more security measures

Comment: Yes, it is enough

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume you are trying to access the database directly from react since it is marked in the tags and you are asking this question;

Usually you don't access databases directly from the client in the case of a web application, you put a layer of APIs in between, so the client make requests to the APIs and only them connect to the database, then you can protect your APIs with a firewall and some auth rules if you need conditional access

Comment: Actually My React/NextJS app makes request to my node app so thi string goes in my node app env file, Do I need TLS/SSL configured with NGINX on these ip addressee for mongodb, what do you think?

Comment: @hasprin SSL is not mandatory unless you want end to end encryption